# Можно ли подключить друг к другу маршрутизатор Cisco 2901 к 2811

Tags: cisco, маршрутизатор, cisco-ios

Как я понял в серии 2811 нет Gigabit а только FastEthernet, можно ли с Gigabit напрямую подсоединить кабель к FastEthernet? Спасибо.

Comment: Ммм, а что мешает? Они обратно совместимы.

Comment: не был уверен что можно гигабит к фаст езернету напрямую подключать, спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Буду краток, да. [Gigabit Ethernet](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet)(1000BASE-T) и [Fast Ethernet](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet)(100BASE-T) [обратно совместимы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_Ethernet):

> Большинство Ethernet-карт и других устройств имеет поддержку нескольких скоростей передачи данных, используя автоопределение (autonegotiation) скорости и дуплексности для достижения наилучшего соединения между двумя устройствами. Если автоопределение не срабатывает, скорость подстраивается под партнёра и включается режим полудуплексной передачи. Например, наличие в устройстве порта Ethernet 10/100 говорит о том, что через него можно работать по технологиям 10BASE-T и 100BASE-TX, а порт Ethernet 10/100/1000 — поддерживает стандарты 10BASE-T, 100BASE-TX и 1000BASE-T.

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/2900-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/data_sheet_c78_553896.html)

говорится, что **Cisco 2901** имеет **Total Onboard WAN 10/100/1000 Ports** т.е. эти порты можно подключать к другому устройству на следующих скоростях 10/100/1000.
Подключай, будет работать.